# C++ type on GPU(Metal), how to save the type of another variable into a class, and make sure all the class instance have the same size?

Tags: c++, templates, gpgpu, metal

Pseudocode on CPU side:

```
class Sphere {
//some property 
}

class Square {
//some property
}

class BVH {
    Type type; // save the type of Sphere or Square, or other types.
    // But the instance of this class should maintain the same size.
}
```

It's possible using `enum` as type, then checking type and branching on GPU. I already got it working on GPU. But if I can save the `type` directly into this class, maybe I can do type cast and use template on GPU. In my understanding, it will reduce all the ugly branching.

All the logic happens on GPU side, CPU side is only preparing data. GPU(Metal) doesn't super class and virtual function, but template is supported. It's better to avoid any std stuff unless I can get the same type on GPU.

Comment: Are you looking for virtual functions?  The question isn't really clear to me.

Comment: Seems you are looking for a *discriminated union*. In modern C++ you get that by using [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

Comment: Could you explain what you exactly want to accomplish? It feels like an XY problem and knowing what you are trying to do might help with answers

Comment: Metal doesn't support virtual functions @StephenNewell

Comment: an instance of type `BVH` is always of same size, you don't have to do anything about that (and you can't), the question is rather: What is `Type` ?

Comment: Hi, I am only preparing data on CPU side with C++ type. Then all the logic happen on GPU.  I guess I shouldn't use any std thing. @john

Comment: It's pseudocode. Just showing there is place to save the type of Sphere/Square/Whatever. That's exactly what I am looking for. @idclev463035818

Comment: My purpose is preparing data on CPU side with C++, then pass it and use it on GPU. To avoid branching, it's better to have the type info directly inside the class. Because it's on GPU, all instance size should be the same. On GPU side, Metal doesn't support super class and virtual function. Template is supported. @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: @iaomw Please [edit] your question to add some details. You basically want to construct a BVH and upload and process it on the GPU. Some of it is clear from your tags and comments, but it would be better to clarify all of this in the question itself. Is your question about how to upload an enum type to the GPU?

Comment: yes please clarify. I just say you tagged templates. You could of course use a `template <typename T> BVH { T instance; }` if you want to store an isntance of either `Sphere` or `Square` inside `BVH` (not quite clear from the question, yuo say you want to store the type, but I suppose you want to store the object). However `BVH<Sphere>` and `BVH<Square>` are two completely unrelated types, now it isnt clear what you really need....

Comment: Hi, I know how to use enum and it's already working on GPU. But I am trying to remove some branching, so here comes this question. @churill

Comment: if `Sphere` and `Square` are different you will need branching. If they are the same, then you dont need two different types

Comment: I guess they will have different size. template <typename T> BVH { T instance; } @idclev463035818

Comment: maybe, maybe not, why do you need them to be same size? As i said `BVH<Sphere>` and `BVH<Square>` are not only potentially of different size, but they are two unrelated types

Comment: When parsing data to GPU, it's better to be the same size in buffer. I know they are different type BVH<T> but there might be a workaround. @idclev463035818

Comment: @iaomw it size is your only concern then `template <typename T> BVH` can add padding such that `BVH<T>` is of some fixed size for any `T`, but I am sure that this isnt the solution to your problem (still looks like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: Hi, I mentioned template, because it's one of available feature on GPU(Metal) may help. The final solution may or may not use it. So, I didn't do any template in my Pseudocode above. It's only offering some background information if anybody don't know Metal. @idclev463035818

Answer (score 0):

Since you talk about parsing to a GPU, I assume that what you need can be an ugly solution, and your focus is on it being efficient rather than readable and nice.This would look something like this:

```
union Figure
{
    Square square;
    Sphere sphere;
};

class BVH {

public:

    enum class FigureType { Square, Sphere };
    BVH(Square square) // or const Square& square, or move...
    {
        type = FigureType::Square;
        figure.square = square;
    }
    BVH(Sphere sphere) { ... }
    // Or instead of the two signatures above,
    // BVH(Figure figure, FigureType type);
    // although that would allow the two parameters to not match.
    // One might even consider to make the enum private.

    void process()
    {
        // or switch
        if(type == FigureType::Square) process_square();
        ...
    }

private:

    FigureType type;
    Figure figure;

    void process_square()
    {
        figure.square.do_something();
    }
}
```

For more about `union`s, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union

But again, `union`s are ugly, and I only mention those as possibility when you really have to do it, ugly very low level programming. If you can go by making `BVH` a template, or if you can introduce some super class `Figure` from which `Square` and `Sphere` inherit and have `BVH` store a pointer to `Figure`, maybe even with `Figure` providing an interface for the sub classes to overwrite, that would be preferable.

Comment: Hi, I already have a branching and type checking version on GPU. In my understanding, our solutions are different but there is no fundamental difference. My purpose is to reduce branching and checking.

Comment: @iaomw mean, in the end, you have to do *something* that discerns which type you have. Even in the polymorphic approach of having a superclass, you'd to that implicitely in the lookup table, right? That said, in the template approach, you would probably do that the least, with it being decided at time of construction.

Comment: @iaomw In any case, if you want to hyper-optimize something on the GPU, I'd go by several approaches and measure time. If the time is not that different, go for the most readable approach.